# Java - I can't get two actionListeners to work right

Tags: java, actionlistener

Here's the ActionListener portion of my code. Focus on the reset button.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (e.getSource() == a[i]) { 
            consultWord(i); 
        }
    }

    if (e.getSource() == reset) {
        Hangman gui = new Hangman();
        System.out.print("test");
        gui.go();
    }
}
```

Obviously there is much more above it (as this is at the VERY end). Button array 1 (top if statement) works perfectly. Button 2 (bottom if statement) doesn't work at all. The test output text does not appear. Here is where I declared the variables. (They are available to all code).

```
JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
private Button a[];
```

And if it means anything to you, here's the code for setting up the a[] buttons.

```
int i;
StringBuffer buffer;
a = new Button[26];
topPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 4,0, 10, 10) );
for (i = 0; i <26; i++) {
    buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append((char)(i+'a'));
    a[i] = new Button(buffer.toString());
    a[i].setSize(100,100);
    a[i].addActionListener( this );
    topPanel.add(a[i]);
}
```

Any ideas why my bottom button isn't doing squat? I'll paste my whole code if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you simply forgot to add the `ActionListener` to your `reset` button? This is missing from your code above…

---

As a side note some suggestions to make your code cleaner:

- The `StringBuffer` is not needed: Simply use `String.valueOf((char)(i+'a'))`
- I would not use the same `ActionListener` for all buttons you have, as this clutters your `actionPerformed` method. [Anonymous inner classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/355177/1347968) can be useful here.