# java Subclases when i make an object?

Tags: java, eclipse, subclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

i have a question about java. i saw this in many sources...

```
Class object = new Class()
{
    // What is this, a subclass or what ?
    public void someRandomMethod()
    { 
    }
};
```

umm if is a subclass, when i make the object the class is executed automatically ? I'm confused

and sorry about my english, i try to do my best.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html). Yes, the class will automatically be extended. This pattern is most commonly used to create callback interfaces such as `Runnable` or `ActionListener`.

```
Thread foo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
});
foo.start(); // Hello World
```

This creates a new instance of `Runnable` and passes it to the `Thread` for execution. This was Java's early substitute for [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: but i can't use that way for simple object-classes ? like the example, or it's only valid for runnable - actionlistener objects ?

Comment: @Kai You can use it for any class you can extend. It wouldn't make sense to create any non-overridden methods in an anonymous class, you wouldn't be able to call them.