# what is meant by argument as given below for method of button object named add

Tags: android-activity

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter +=19;
        display.setText("your total is "+ counter);
    }
});
```

i was learning android programming but what this code means here
add is `Button` object , and we are using method `setOnClickListener` and basically what is 
passed as a argument to it , which is confusing.
counter is `int` variable and display is `TextView` object used for producing text when 
button is pressed.
please reply

Comment: I think your question is not focussing on android explicitly. If you are really referring to the argument passed into the method and what the argument exactly means. Then you are asking a more general question like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/355167/3165552) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10778578/3165552). Since this post had only 5 views for now, you can think about adding more tags to your post to attract a broader user group to read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is a  **new anonymous object of an anonymous type subclassing from `View.OnClickListener`** being added to your button called `add`. The definition refers to the argument given by this code `new View.OnClickListener() { /*...*/ }`.

That is what happens in your line. Whenever the button `add` is pressed the method `onClick` will be called on the anonymous object being passed in. The code inside the overriden `onClick` method then gets executed.

You can make it clearer by separating the anonymous class into a named class like the following:

```
class MyButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int counter;
    private TextView display;
    public MyButtonListener(int counter, TextView display) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.display = display;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter +=19;
        display.setText("your total is "+ counter);
    }
}
```

And still use an anonymously created object, since it is not bound to a named variable and pass it again directly to your `add` button. But now you use a named class called `MyButtonListener`

```
add.setOnClickListener(new MyButtonListener(counter, display));
```

Notice that now you must pass everthing needed into the object. Like the `counter` and `display` variables.

Hope this helps

The listener thing is basically a [pattern called observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which can be used to decouple multiple handlers to a button from the button itself. This way they both doesnt know directly about each other, which allow both to evolve independently by the use of inheritance.

Anonymous classes are a way to quickly create subclasses. For more information about anonymous classes take a look at [this site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes)