# How to make a TextView Clickable with a extra ID in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am developing a Android Application, where i have multiple textView and I want those textview clickable. When I will click those textView I will get a common empty form but with a static ID in the top for every textview.
For example: If I have 3 product name in 3 text view, if I click on textView1, a previously made layout will be shown and there will be a static ID with my product name in the top, then there will be form to filling up the details of the product.If I click on the textView2 then the form will be same only the Static ID and the product name will change.
I hope you guys understood what I wanted to explain.
I am new in application development so I need some simple solution.
So far I have made a layout of my form and I have also made a clickable Layout. So I need to know how I would make the class and function to call the layout and plus the static ID.
**Layout of the product name and the Clickable TextView:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/p85"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/p85"
    android:ems="7"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textColor="#375C34"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/product_list_view"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**ProductList.java file that call the product_list.xml**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProductList extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.product_list);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In xml in your textview put :
android:onClick="onClick"

And have this

```
public void onClick(View v)    {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.TextViewFromXml): 
       // do something
        break;
    } 
}
```

Or Remove this

```
  Textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: The onClick() method should be outside of the Activity right?

Comment: I think static, but not sure if it is safe, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815101/view-onclicklistener-a-function-or-interface

Comment: No need of static, but should be inside of the activity and should accept the parameter View

Answer (score 0):

First set Tag(i.e your Static ID) to TextView and then set Clicklistner

```
      tv.setTag("1234");
      tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        myId=tv.getTag();
        }
    });
```