# Interview : Is it possible to create a class without name?

Tags: java, c++, class, oop

During my interview, interviewer asked me

*Can we create class without name ?*

Since, I was not sure, if it is really possible to create a class without name. So, I said **No**.

Later,  I tried Googling and found, others are also looking for the answer of the same question, but I didn't found clear answer.

I will appreciate, if anyone clearly explain about this class. I mean, what that class technically known as and how can we instantiate this class ?

Comment: +1:  While the question itself is fairly simply, it got me thinking about new things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's called an anonymous class/struct.

In C++:

```
class {
} x;
```

`x` is an object of the type, and you can't create any more, because, well, how would you, given that the class doesn't have a name and all....

> how would one call constructor and destructors

You don't. In both Java and C++ constructors and destructors hold the same name as the class (they're not PHP - `__construct` or whatever), and the missing name kind of gets in the way.

Comment: Such a class cannot have user-declared constructors.

Comment: which means we can't create any object of that class... ??

Comment: Actually, it seems you can create a copy using `auto` in C++11.

Comment: please provide some good links, where i can learn more about this class... i mean.. why do we need such type of class.. and etc..

Comment: @coders I don't have a binder of links - just google for anonymous class - now that you know what it's called, it should be easy.

Comment: @coders If you don't know why you'd use such a construct, why would you ask if it exists?

Comment: The C++03 Standard actually refers to these as "unnamed" classes, not "anonymous".  You can `typedef` such a construct, as with `typedef class {} Thingy;` thereby making it easier to instantiate such things: `Thingy t;`  But then, if you're doing this in C++, I'd wonder why you really want it to be unnamed in the first place. Perhaps to make declaration of a non-trivial constructor impossible?  Hmmm...

Comment: @JohnDibling that would make a good question IMO (but I think you already answered it).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  I've actually never thought of creating such a construct before.  I'm pondering the possible uses.

Comment: it could have an assignment operator but that couldn't return a reference to the class nor could it take the class const reference as its parameter.

Comment: A comment on the downvote is always welcomed. I want to know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Its also called an anonymous class in Java.

```
// create a new instance of an anonymous class.
Serializable s = new Serializable() {
};
```

Note: In the JVM, all classes have a name, it's generated by the compiler for you.

You can't define constructors, but it can have an instance initializer block which does much the same thing.

Comment: Do you mean an instance initializer block?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, anonymous classes can't have static initializer blocks. ;)

Comment: Descriptions of anonymous classes always seemed off to me. The class always has a name, instance may not.

Comment: IMHO, instances don't have names unless you add a field like `name`. Class has a given name or it is anonymous (in which case the compiler gives it name)

Comment: *In the JVM, all classes have a name*, technically you can have a class w/ an empty string as name. I have not tried `null`, `ClassLoader.checkName(String)` considers `null` fine but I am not sure about the JVM code (and I am too lazy to dig it)

Answer (score 0):

In java, you can create "anonymous inner classes", for a detailed answer see [How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)