# Creating instance of static abstract class

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

I know that abstract classes cannot be instantiated. But I have a doubt in the code below. This code is a part of android bitmap fun demo ( http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip).

```
// ImageWorkerAdapter class is nested in another abstract class ImageWorker
public static abstract class ImageWorkerAdapter
{
public abstract Object getItem(int num);
public abstract int getSize();
}

//this snippet is seen in Images.java
public final static ImageWorkerAdapter imageWorkerUrlsAdapter = new ImageWorkerAdapter() { 
@Override
public Object getItem(int num) {
return Images.imageUrls[num];
}
```

I cannot understand how it is possible to create an instance of an abstract class. Please help me to understand this code.

Comment: @Nambari: no, they can't. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29

Comment: @Nambari: I have an exact reference: the javadoc I linked to, which says: "Throws: InstantiationException - if this Class represents an abstract class"

Comment: @JBNizet: This code works perfectly in eclipse.

Comment: @VysakhPrem: No, no I am not saying it won't work. It should work. But the reason what I have in my mind is different. JB Nizet clarified that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you show does not show an abstract class being instantiated.

It shows an [anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java) being instantiated. In this case, the anonymous class extends an abstract class. You can also implement interfaces in anonymous classes, `Runnable` being a very common example.

Answer (score 6):

This code represents the initialization of an anonymous class extending `ImageWorkerAdapter` abstract class:

```
new ImageWorkerAdapter() { 
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int num) {
    return Images.imageUrls[num];
}
```

Indeed, the **anonymous** implementation is defined between the curly braces.

As being an anonymous class, it's perfectly valid to rely on an abstract class or interface.

Comment: At the first sight, I was confused. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not instantiate an abstract class, but defines new anonymous abstract class which among others extends and implement (override) other abstract class.