# Java syntax confusion in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am a newbie in Android Development, how can I understand this snippets?

```
private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() 
{   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.exit(0);
        finish();
    }
};
```

OnClickListener is a static interface, we can't use "new" to initialize an object. Who can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java

Comment: first search in here or developer.android.com then if you  find nothing then ask a question

Comment: anonymous class. relation to android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can create an [Anonymous Class](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~tmh/courses/allJava/Anonymous.html) if you implement all necessary requirements of the interface being presented. This is acting as a new class definition implementing OnClickListener, and overriding its one necessary method, onClick(View).

Comment: i appreciate it ,you helped me a lot