# Separate a java listener to its own function?

Tags: java, android

Can I break the set-listener line into smaller pieces?

Here is the code I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Preference button = (Preference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("exitlink");      

      button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                finish();   
                return true;
             }
        });
```

I would like this to look something like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Preference button = (Preference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("exitlink");      
    if(button != null) {
         button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(onPreferenceClick);
    }        
}

public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
    finish();   
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above nearly works already. Use your above code with this tiny change:

```
button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
```

Then you just let your class implement the specific interface needed, in this case `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener`.

In addition to dmon's suggestion below about using variables for this, it is also possible to write a function that returns a listener, which is very useable when you want to have similar listeners but with slight changes, like in the example below.

```
private Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener getListener(int listenerId) {
    return new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            Log.i("MyTag", "Listener " + listenerId + " invoked!");
            finish();   
            return true;
         }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to add implements OnPreferenceClickListener to my class, but that did it.  I guess that's what you meant though, so, :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a variable outside of your method:

```
    private Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener listener = new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            finish();   
            return true;
         }
    };
```

Then you use it as a variable: `setListener(listener)`. This would allow you to have multiple instances of the same listener class in your Activity.

Comment: I was just about to edit my answer and add this option. This is very useful in cases of multiple different listeners needed. You can also have a function that returns a Listener :) Also very useful. The beauty of Java interfaces :)

Comment: Hehe, yeah we could add that as yet another one.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, even though you cannot pass a method name to `setOnPreferenceClickListener` you can create a variable of a type that extends `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener`. In your original code, that is actually exactly what you are doing: you are creating an object of an [anonymous inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java).

The advantage of this approach, say over Simon André Forsberg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983373/18573) above is of scope: it keeps the listener functionality in that small block, instead of potentially all over the class.

Creating a separate variable outside the method as in dmon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983406/18573) loses one big benefit of the anonymous inner class, that they can access the variables in the containing scope: in your original code, the listener can access the variables `button` and `savedInstanceState`. This is not possible with a separate variable defined outside the function.

None of this means that you must use anonymous inner class. Oracle has an excellent tutorial titled [General Information about Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html) that you will greatly benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. The set-listener requires an instance of listener, so you always need to create one. And I don't think it's a good manner for activity implementing listener interfaces.

The workaround is that you can use annotations with reflection, such as http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/. This may make the code cleaner, but  also introduces dependencies.

Comment: And I don't think it's a good manner to include reflection unless you really have to. I see no need for reflection here.

Comment: Yes, i agree, but it can just make the set-listener shorter, and it's universal.