# Instantiate an abstract class or interface, possible?

Tags: java

This works good.

```
package abstracttest;

public abstract class AbstractClass implements NewInter {

    public abstract void doStuff();

    public void doStuff2() {
        System.out.println("in doStuff2");
    }

    /*
     * public static void main(String a[]) { AbstractClass ab = new
     * AbstractClass() {
     * 
     * @Override public void doStuff() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     * System.out.println(" doStuff "); }
     * 
     * @Override public void doInter() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     * 
     * } };
     * 
     * ab.doStuff2(); ab.doStuff();
     * 
     * NewInter ni = new NewInter() {
     * 
     * @Override public void doInter() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     * System.out.println("do Inter"); }
     * 
     * }; ni.doInter();
     * 
     * AbstractClass ab1 = new AbstractClass(); }
     */

}

interface NewInter {

    String con = "Hell";

    void doInter();
}

class Impl extends AbstractClass {

    @Override
    public void doInter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        AbstractClass ab = new AbstractClass() {

            @Override
            public void doInter() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("impl doInter");
            }

            @Override
            public void doStuff() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("impl doStuff");
            }

        };
        ab.doInter();
        ab.doStuff();

        NewInter ni1 = new NewInter() {

            @Override
            public void doInter() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        ni1.doInter();
    }

}
```

I was able to instantiate the `abstract class` and `interface` both from within the abstract class' `main()` and from the `class Impl`.
How is this possible?
I was expecting an exception but the invocation worked correctly.
Can someone please explain the phenomena? I am confused.

> A Java abstract class also cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists.

I read this in a [blog](http://javapapers.com/core-java/abstract-and-interface-core-java-2/difference-between-a-java-interface-and-a-java-abstract-class/). What does it mean?

And is there any other way of invoking the constructor of an abstract class? Please let me know if there is.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this, or is this purely an academic question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I do this:

```
new AbstractClass() {
   public void methodToImplement() {
   }
}
```

it's creating an anonymous class *derived* from the abstract class. It's so called (anonymous) since the class definition doesn't have it's own accessible name and you can't access the definition again. The definition/instantiation occur together e.g.

```
AbstractClass ac = new AbstractClass() {
   ...
}
```

(it's a *subclass* of `AbstractClass`)

Note that you can do this for both interfaces and abstract classes, but you'll have to implement the required methods appropriately.

The above is often used to implement simple interfaces/abstract classes in a concise form, often as inner classes within callbacks.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java) for more info, and the [Nested Class tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you please explain **A Java abstract class cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists**; the 7th point, in the [blog](http://javapapers.com/core-java/abstract-and-interface-core-java-2/difference-between-a-java-interface-and-a-java-abstract-class/)?

Comment: I think it means that you can have a *static* main() method and thus run com.example.AbstractClass from the command line. Note that's *not* instantiating an instance of the class, since the main method is static

Answer (score 14):

No, you didn't instantiate them. You have only created anonymous classes that implement the interface or extend the abstract class. Objects of these anonymous classes types are actually instantiated.

Comment: That is a wonderful explanation. Now I understand that we are subclassing the abstract class and not creating an instance. But can you please explain about this point **A Java abstract class also cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists.** I have already mentioned it in the question.

Comment: You are building some instances of anonymous class type and call their methods. You can do this inside main or inside any other method.

Comment: So you mean to say that ** A Java abstract class also cannot be instantiated, but can be invoked if a main() exists**, this means it can be invoked using anonymous inner class and not through some other way?

Comment: Once you have a reference to it, you can invoke its methods.

Comment: I meant invoking its constructor not its methods

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24818/discussion-between-freakyuser-and-dan)

Comment: A constructor of a class is invoked either directly, which in the abstract classes is not possible or by a constructor of a subclass.