# Methods inside methods

Tags: java, methods

Is it syntactically correct to have a method inside the main method in Java? For example

```
class Blastoff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //countdown method inside main
        public static void countdown(int n) {

            if (n == 0) {
                System.out.println("Blastoff!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(n);
                countdown(n - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not method inside methods, that's called recursion. And yes, your algorithm looks right.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza While `countdown` is recursive, it's also lexically nested inside `main`.

Comment: I am asking about the part where I have the countdown method in the main method, because my compiler says there is an error in that line

Comment: @delnan well, that's code problem. OP just needs to move the `countdown` function outside `main`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's the question, duh!

Comment: @delnan well, it would be better to **post an answer** instead of wasting time in comments ;)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am not qualified to answer Java questions (see the answer by ruakh? I wouldn't have thought of anonymous inner classes). I am only qualified to point out when people miss the question ;-)

Answer (score 7):

No, not directly; however, it is possible for a method to contain a *local inner class*, and of course that inner class can contain methods. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/355167/978917) gives some examples of that.

In your case, however, you probably just want to call `countdown` from inside `main`; you don't actually need its entire definition to be inside `main`. For example:

```
class Blastoff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        countdown(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }

    private static void countdown(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("Blastoff!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(n);
            countdown(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that I've declared `countdown` as `private`, so that it can only be called from within the `Blastoff` class, which I'm assuming was your intent?)

Comment: Yes that is my intent thanks. I am still getting the hang of the whole class/methods/objects structure what exactly does the `countdown(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));` line do?

Comment: @user1940007: The `args` argument to `main` is an array of the command-line arguments, as `String` instances. `args[0]` is the first command-line argument, as a `String`. [The `Integer.parseInt` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) parses that `String` as a base-10 integer, and returns an `int`. So `countdown(Integer.parseInt(args[0]))` parses the first command-line argument as a base-10 integer, and calls `countdown` with it. (Try running your program as `java Blastoff 10`, and you'll see what I mean.)