# Java ArrayList and other stuff

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I started working on my first java project, it's some kind of a very basic roleplaying game (no gui, of course). Now I'm working on the spells. I created "Spell" class (includes name, effect and cost). I created SpellsList class, that should include all spells. I have "Effects" class that describes what's the spell's effect (it's just for testing right now). When a spell-caster casts a spell then I want to get the relevant spell effect, so the relevant effect will take care of the spell's effect (I'll work on the effects later, now it's just for testing). I have a dice roller, but it doesn't matter for now.

I have a few questions:

1. What's wrong with the code ?
2. why " public static void main(String[] args) {" is crucial ?
3. Would you implement the spells in a better way ?

   ```
   public class Spell {
   private String name;
   private String effect;
   private int cost;

   Spell(String name, String effect, int cost){
   this.name = name;
   this.effect = effect;
   this.cost = cost;
   }

   String getSpellName(){
   return name;
   }

   String getEffect(){
   return effect;
   }

   int getCost(){
   return cost;
   }
   ```

   }

}

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.List;

public class SpellsList {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    List<Spell> spellsList = new ArrayList<Spell>();
    spellsList.add(new Spell("Fireball", "damage", 5));
    spellsList.add(new Spell("Ice Storm", "damage", 8));
    spellsList.add(new Spell("Heal", "heal", 8));


static String getSpellEffect(String spellName) {

    for (Iterator iter = spellsList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        if (iter.next().equals(spellName)) {
            iter.next().Spell.getEffect();
            break;
        }
    }
    }


}
```

}

```
public class Effects {

int damage(int n, int dice, int bonus){

    int damage = Dice.roll(n,dice,bonus);
    System.out.println("You dealt" + damage + "damage to the enemy!");
    return damage;
}

int heal(int n, int dice, int bonus){

    int heal = Dice.roll(n,dice,bonus);
    System.out.println("You healed" + heal + " hit points!");
    return heal;
}
```

}

```
public class Dice {

public static int roll(int dice){

    int sum = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((dice - 1) + 1));
    return sum;
}

public static int roll(int n, int dice){

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((dice - 1) + 1));
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int roll(int n, int dice, int bonus){

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((dice - 1) + 1));
    }
    return (sum + n*bonus);
}
```

}

Comment: what is the problem ? and "public static void main(String[] args) {" is the entry point of the progam, you have to start somewhere.

Comment: What is the error\issue with code right now? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Your code doesn't have balanced number of `{` and `}`. Try to indent it properly (use IDE or any other editor which can indent code for you).

Comment: Maybe here some { got lost, in my code it's fine. The problem is with getSpellEffect, I get on the declaration line illegal start of expression, and in this method spellsList and Spell are shown in red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a method named getSpellEffect() inside the main() method. You cannot have methods inside methods. Check [Methods inside methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045272/methods-inside-methods)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

    public class SpellsList {

        static List<Spell> spellsList = new ArrayList<Spell>();

        static {

            spellsList.add(new Spell("Fireball", "damage", 5));
            spellsList.add(new Spell("Ice Storm", "damage", 8));
            spellsList.add(new Spell("Heal", "heal", 8));

        }

        static String getSpellEffect(String spellName) {

            String spellEffect = "";

            for (Iterator<Spell> iter = spellsList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Spell spell = iter.next();
                if (spellName.equals(spell.getSpellName())) {
                    spellEffect = spell.getEffect();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return spellEffect;

        }
    }
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(SpellsList.getSpellEffect("Fireball"));

    }

}
```

Comment: I created a Main class just with "public static void main(String[] args) {
" , and omitted the line from SpellList class, but then I I had a problem with adding object to the list (add was red). How do I solve that ?

Comment: While the code can be improved, but since you are still developing, can you try the code mentioned above. I modified the SpellsList class,

Comment: When I use your code then I get an error in the for loop that java can't find symbol spellsList.....

Comment: Is it possible to move the main method to Main class? When I did that before I couldn't use "add" do you know why ?

Comment: Did you move the spellsList variable above the main method and declare it as static.

Comment: I just moved the decalaration of the main method from SpellsList class to Main class.

Comment: So, you created a class named **Main.java** and moved the **main()** method there

Comment: Yes, that's what I did

Comment: Can you try the above code and check if it works.

Comment: It works. Do you know why it solves the problem ?

Comment: It worked for me. Maybe you can share your code.

Comment: Yo were trying to access spellsList variable in **Main.java**, where it was not accessible The way to use it in the main() method would be, `SpellsList.spellsList.add(new Spell("Fireball", "damage", 5));`

Comment: Now I get what the problem was, thanks for solving this issue :)