# How to call a method that has an interface as a parameter?

Tags: java

I have the following method in a class:

```
public void Process(Measurable x)
{
    String y = x.getResult();

    for (int k = 0; k<item.length; k++)
    {
        if (y.equals(item[k])) tally[k]++;
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I call the Process method? Calling it with

```
Process(Measurable y);
```

in the default constructor or the driver class doesn't work, nor does calling it with no parameter (as I would expect).

Comment: Provide an implementation instance of the `Measurable` interface. You can even use an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) to handle the job.

Comment: What driver class are you talking about? does this method belong to the class `Process`?

Comment: Well what argument do you *want* to use? Do you understand that you're trying to supply information to the method? Where do you expect that information to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would call it with a class implementing the `Measurable` interface. For example:

Assume you have the class:

```
class Foo implements Measurable {
    @Overrride
    public String getResult(){ return "bar"; }
}
```

And then you could call `Process` like so:

```
Process(new Foo());
```

This takes advantage of an Object Oriented Programming idea called [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

People have also mentioned that you can use [anonymous inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java) like so:

```
Process(new Measurable(){
    @Override
    public String getResult() {
        return "hey!";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have known that.

Answer (score 2):

```
// How to call your Process method
Measureable y = new ConcreteMeasureable()
Process(y);

// Assuming you have something like this... 
class ConcreteMeasureable implements Measureable
{
    @Override
    public String getResult()
    {
        return "something here";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the `Process` method with an instance of a class that implements the `Measurable` interface; even an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) would do.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure that's very basic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object that implements `Measurable`:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }

  public interface Measurable {
    String getResult();
  }

  // Here to make `Process` compile.
  String[] item;
  int[] tally;

  public void Process(Measurable x) {
    String y = x.getResult();

    for (int k = 0; k < item.length; k++) {
      if (y.equals(item[k])) {
        tally[k]++;
      }
    }
  }

  static class M implements Measurable {

    @Override
    public String getResult() {
      return "M";
    }

  }

  public void test() {
    // Create an Object on the fly that implements Measurable (in a rather silly way).
    Process(new Measurable() {

      @Override
      public String getResult() {
        return "Hello";
      }

    });
    // Do it a bit more normally.
    Process(new M());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat objects that implement the interface as the interface type using [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), even though you can't directly instantiate an object of it.

For example, if `Measurable` is an interface, and we have a class like this:

```
public class MeasuredObject implements Measurable {
    ...
}
```

Then we can do something like the following:

```
MeasuredObject object = new MeasuredObject();
Measurable measurableObject = (Measurable) object;
```

This should show that calling your method is possible.

```
Process(measurableObject);
```

While the explicit type casting isn't necessary, it should help illustrate the concept.

*(Small side note: consider adhering to Java coding standards and making your method names into `camelCase`.  It makes your code much more readable.)*

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        driver.process(foo);
    }

    public void process(Measurable x) {
        String y = x.getResult();

        for (int k = 0; k<item.length; k++) {
            if (y.equals(item[k])) tally[k]++;
        }
    }

    private class Foo implements Measurable {
        String getResult() {
            /* Do stuff */
        }
    }

    public interface Measurable {
        String getResult();
    }
}
```

There's also a `y`, `item`, and `tally` in there somewhere.

P.S. In Java method names are generally lower camel cased.