# I need help understanding the scheduleAtFixedRate method of theTimer class in java

Tags: java, syntax

Being a fan of the [Pomodoro technique](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/) I'm making myself a countdown timer to keep me on task with my homework. This particular project, however, is NOT homework. :)

Stack has a LOT of questions about using timers to control delays before user input and the like, but not a lot on standalone timers. I've run across this code from a friend, and have studied the class on Java Documentation.

```
public class Stopwatch {
    static int interval;
    static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
        String secs = sc.nextLine();
        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        timer = new Timer();
        interval = Integer.parseInt( secs );
        System.out.println(secs);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println(setInterval());
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }
    private static final int setInterval()
    {
        if( interval== 1) timer.cancel();
        return --interval;
    }
}
```

There is some syntax that's not clear to me. Consider:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
     public void run()
     {
          System.out.println(setInterval());
     }
}, delay, period);
```

I'm not understanding how the parentheses and braces work. At first glance, given the usage of `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` I can see the `delay` and `period` parameters, but not an open paren preceding first parameter.

Is my first parameter actually this whole block of code? I would expect the whole block to be surrounded by parentheses...but it's not. Is this a common syntax in java? I've never run across it before.

new TimerTask()
{
     public void run()
     {
          System.out.println(setInterval());
     }
}

I just want to clarify that I understand it before I start mucking about with changes.

Comment: `This particular project, however, is NOT homework. :)` Sounds like something someone trying to get StackOverflow to solve their homework would say.

ಠ~ಠ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
     public void run()
     {
          System.out.println(setInterval());
     }
}, delay, period);
```

That code is equivalent to this refactoring, where the `new TimerTask` is assigned to a local variable.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
{
     public void run()
     {
          System.out.println(setInterval());
     }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
```

Of course the weird part has just moved upwards a bit. What is this `new TimerTask` stuff, exactly?

Java has special syntax for defining [anonymous inner classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java). Anonymous classes are a syntactical convenience. Instead of defining a sub-class of `TimerTask` elsewhere you can define it and its `run()` method right at the point of usage.

The code above is equivalent to the following, with the anonymous `TimerTask` sub-class turned into an explicit named sub-class.

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
{
     public void run()
     {
          System.out.println(setInterval());
     }
}

TimerTask task = new MyTimerTask();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the first parameter is the entire code block:

```
new TimerTask()
{
     public void run()
     {
          System.out.println(setInterval());
     }
}
```

These declarations are called *Anonymous classes* and are explained in more detail in [the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks also for what they're called so I know what to look for in the tutorials. :)

Comment: @dwwilson66: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote helpful answers, and mark the best one as accepted if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). You need to **study inner classes for understanding this**. Generally such classes are used when you do not need the class to be used else where in your code. You cannot use it else where just because you **dont have reference pointing to it.**
You can also replace the above code as follows :

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Timer task code goes here.
             System.out.println(setInterval());
        }

    }
    MyTimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, delay, period);
```