# How do I run code once every second in java?

Tags: java, timer, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have the following code, but I want it to run once every second, so if questNumber changes, then currentQuestStats will also change.

*Editor's note: pastebin link with code that used to be here no longer works.*

Comment: Please do not post your code on an external site.  You can include the code in your question.  That way, if that link dies, the question will remain valid.

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score 3):

use `ScheduledExecutorService` which added in JAVA 5, you must import following classes.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

---

you can use it like below:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO add your code here:
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

---

**Answer**

- make a method called `checkQuestNumber()` in `QuestsManagement` class.
- also create a constructor for `QuestsManagement`
- initialize `currentQuestStats` with this value (`§e§lCurrent quest: Kill 1 zombie`).
- make `currentQuestStats`  and `questNumber` private and encapsulate them.

here is your `QuestsManagement` after those changes

```
public class QuestsManagement {

    private String currentQuestStats = "§e§lCurrent quest: Kill 1 zombie";
    private int questNumber = 1;

    public String getCurrentQuestStats() {
        return currentQuestStats;
    }

    public int getQuestNumber() {
        return questNumber;
    }

    QuestsManagement() {
        ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               checkQuestNumber();
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    void checkQuestNumber() {

        if (questNumber == 1) {
            currentQuestStats = "§e§lCurrent quest: Kill 1 zombie";
            // change manual!
            questNumber = 2;
        } else if (questNumber == 2) {
            currentQuestStats = "§e§lCurrent quest: Walk 100 blocks";
            // change manual!
            questNumber = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

## To Test Code!

### in your custom command file

create an instance of `QuestsManagement` and use `getCurrentQuestStats()` method

```
QuestsManagement m = new QuestsManagement();
player.addChatMessage("Test" + QuestsManagement.getCurrentQuestStats());
```

Comment: Later one (scheduledExecutorService)is a good approach!!

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. Where exactly do I put the last bit of code? (Where I create an instace of QuestsManagement and call checkQuestNumber())?

Comment: hi,  i edited  the answer check it!

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to check if the code is working? I started up Minecraft, and went into a world. Sadly, I have not setup actually using the currentQuestStats, so I do not know if the code is working.

Comment: @Betterjakers i added a `EDITS` part in answer, recheck it.

Comment: I joined the world, and nothing is happening in the console. Also, I am a bit confused on the "change manually" stuff. Anyway, thanks for the help you are giving me!

Comment: I do not think the repeat every 1 second part of the code is working, as there is no console output, and the variable "currentQuestStats" does not change.

Comment: @Betterjakers did you changed `checkQuestNumber` method as it is in `Edits` ?

Comment: What? I don't understand what you mean. I am sorry, but I am still learning Java. Your help is greatly appreciated! EDIT: Yes, I did change it as in Edits.

Comment: @Betterjakers Good Luck man, i mean maybe your changes on code is wrong or is not as i answered, make sure your code is like [this](http://pastebin.com/s0bAq8gN), then run it and enjoy.

Comment: Hm.. alright. This is what I did: I made currentQuestStats a static, and in my custom command file, this is the code:                              player.addChatMessage("Test" + QuestsManagement.currentQuestStats);                                                      This should make it say this to me when I run the command: "TestCurrent quest: Kill 1 zombie". It does not, it only says "Test". That means currentQuestStats is not setting, and I don't know why.

Comment: thats because `currentQuestStats` is empty string first(`""`) wait just a moment i fix them

Comment: @Betterjakers i changed some parts, [check this](http://pastebin.com/5xxYFmGr), im sure it's working now

Comment: It is not working, sadly. Here is my QuestsManagement: http://pastebin.com/16ddWPe2                                                               and here is my command: http://pastebin.com/TLUV2ngb. I did everything you said, but it is not working.

Comment: @Betterjakers make sure you initialize `currentQuestNumber` like ` String currentQuestStats = "§e§lCurrent quest: Kill 1 zombie";`

Comment: Like this? http://pastebin.com/1Ge6yi0K                                                                    This doesn't work, but I think it's what you mean.

Comment: @RahmatWaisi Again, I don't know if it is doing that code every second, because nothing in there is working. It won't set currentQuestStats to "Curremt quest: Kill 1 zombie" when questNumber is 1. If I put "System.out.println("Test");" into the code, it does not say "Test" in console every second

Comment: Read the answer again, it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

Do it using multithreading. Here's the code:

```
public class QuestsManagement implements Runnable{
    public String currentQuestStats = "";
    public int questNumber = 1;
    Thread t;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(questNumber == 1) {
                currentQuestStats = "§e§lCurrent quest: Kill 1 zombie";
                if(questNumber == 2) {
                    currentQuestStats = "§e§lCurrent quest: Walk 100 blocks";
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new QuestsManagement());

        t.start();

        //do something else here... whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add all of the code you want to run to a method.  I will assume you will call it `update()`.

What you then want to do is add something like the following to your main program loop:

```
long nextTick = currentTimeMillis() + 1000 ;//Set time of first game tick

QuestsManagement quest = new QuestsManagement();

//Main Loop
while (true) {
    /*
    Do some other stuff
    */

    if (System. currentTimeMillis() >= nextTick) {//Check to see if it is time or past time to update
        nextTick += 1000//Set next tick to one second in the future
        quest.update();
    }
}
```

Please note that you are missing the `update()` method, the constructor, and any getters and setters.  I would also refrain from making your variables public.

Comment: Excelent that should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are multiple answers possible to this question. Java provides various ways to perform time operations. One approach is to use Timer class.

```
public class QuestsManagement {

public String currentQuestStats = "";
public int questNumber = 1;
static Timer t;
TimerTask task;
public static void main(String[] args) {
t = new Timer();
task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(questNumber == 1) {
                currentQuestStats = "§e§lCurrent quest: Kill 1 zombie";
            if(questNumber == 2) {
                 currentQuestStats = "§e§lCurrent quest: Walk 100 blocks";

         }
 } ;

t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task , 1000, 1000 );
}}
```

import following

`import java.util.Timer;`

`import java.util.TimerTask;`

Comment: This code does not work. This is what the errors look like: https://gyazo.com/4bd39a8cd7208119b0354deb821cdda4 (I don't know how to paste the image directly into this comment)

Comment: make changes `static Timer t;` and also look at following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571169/i-need-help-understanding-the-scheduleatfixedrate-method-of-thetimer-class-in-ja

Comment: @Betterjakers check edits

Comment: Your edits did not work. There are still the same errors. The only error that went away was the one on this line: "t = new Timer();". All the others stayed.

Comment: can you say which errors come? @Betterjakers

Comment: As shown in my first comment, there is a link to gyazo showing the errors.

Comment: @Betterjakers according to image you are missing one closing braces `}` . and If you have solve that then tell me what is the actual error not the line number in code.

Comment: @Betterjakers does your problem solve?