# "new View.onClickListner() {...}" What is it?

Tags: java, android

I started reading an android tutorial and I found an example where I  found the following situation:

```
button.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() { //SOME CODE} );
```

Now View.OnClickListener is an interface, then what I understand is that doing in this way I create an instance of an object of OnClickListener type that is formed by the code in the braces. Is it so? But is it a java particular way to make things easier or is it a particular android programming choice? Because I never saw something like this in Java, maybe I didn't study a lot.

Comment: it exists in java log before android

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that there was a name for this construction and couldn't make a research. thanks for the link

Comment: @Oli although that answers the question I wouldn't consider it an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's called an `anonymous inner class`.

it's `anonymous` because you never actually declare it as a variable,  you just call `new`.  It doesn't have a (variable) name so it is anonymous.

It's `inner`, because it's inside of another class and is not publicly accessible. Well, it can be accessed through `button`, but that is specific to this usage.

and finally it is a `class`.

You'll see it in Java everywhere, and it is very common in Android.

Another alternative is to have your class implement that interface, and pass `this`.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's anonymous because it has no name! (I mean the class that implements `OnClickListener`).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it so?

Yes. This is called creating an instance of [an anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

> But is it a java particular way to make things easier or is it a particular android programming choice?

This is certainly valid Java syntax. I think it may be a bit more popular in Android development than elsewhere, in part based upon Google-supplied code samples. In fact, I have been trying to reduce my use of this idiom in my book, as others found it confusing, as you did.