# A constructor in an interface?

Tags: java

I’m reading an article about inner class. I found an example that demonstrates anonymous inner class (mentioned below).

```
  button1 = new JButton();
  button2 = new JButton();
  ...
  button1.addActionListener(
     new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
     {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
        {
           // do something
        }
     }
  );
```

According to the example it creates an inner class for responding to a button using ActionListener  interface.  As I know an interface does not have a constructor. But I’m wondering, how they call a constructor.

**"new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
}"**

Comment: it is not an constructor call, it creates an anonymous inner class which implements `ActionListener`

Answer (score 2):

An interface does not have a constructor, but an anonymous class does: like all classes, it extends `java.lang.Object` implicitly, therefore it can call the `Object`'s parameterless constructor.

Moreover, `Object`'s constructor is the only constructor you could call, because anonymous classes cannot define custom constructors.

Of course in addition to extending `java.lang.Object` your anonymous class implements `ActionListener` - that's why you can pass it to the `addActionListener` method.

Answer (score 0):

you are constructing a subclass.

Comment: To be clearer-  you're defining a new class.  This class is annonymous-  it has no name, and exists only in that function.  You can't create more of them.  But that line defines it and creates an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a quick look at the Java Specification - specifically the [Default Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) Section. You get a constructor because when you instantiate an instance of an interface it would be an Object.

Quote from the spec:

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is
>   implicitly declared.

Answer (score 0):

`new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){ }`
This statement creates an anonymous class object that implements `ActionListener` interface.
**That is you are *invoking anonymous class default constructor not the interface one.***
According to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>   1.The new operator
>   2.The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend.
>   3.Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a normal class instance creation expression. Note: In the case of implementing an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

*Anonymous inner class: An inner class with no name.*

Now the only detail here we care about is, this new class should *subType* the interface and for that we provide the necessary method implementations.

The constructor for this class is a *default* one and performs the job well because there are no instance variables associated.

Answer (score 0):

[How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-anonymous-class-example/

Answer (score 0):

You are not instantiating an interface.  You are asking the compiler to create an anonymous class implementing that interface and immediately create an instance of this class.

The best way to demonstrate this is to go to the "class" directory.  You will find files of the form `className$1.class`, `className$2.class`, etc.  These files correspond to those anonymous classes.  If you were instantiating the interface itself, there would be no need for these new class files (and the anonymous classes they contain, of course).

Answer (score 0):

That is how Anonymous Classes are(syntax wise).

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

The anonymous class expression consists of the following:

1. The new operator
2. **The name of an interface to implement** or a class to extend.
3. **Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a
   normal class instance creation expression. Note: In the case of
   implementing an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an
   empty pair of parentheses.**
4. A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the
   body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.