# What exactly is happening in this Java code snippet?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Here is the code:

```
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
    {
       public void run()
       {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                 try 
                 {   
                   // System.out.println(" ITERATION = ");

                     pachubeCLI.update(78164);  

                 } 
                 catch (PachubeException e)
                 {
                        // If an exception occurs it will print the error message from the
                        // failed HTTP command
                        System.err.println(e.errorMessage);
                 } 
                 catch (IOException e) 
                 {
                        System.err.println(e);
                 } 

             }
        }
    }, 0, 5*1000);
```

I can tell that the code is basically being used to schedule an operation using an object of the `Timer` class. The parameters passed to the `schedule` method , according to eclipse , are `(TimerTask task,long delay, long period)`. But looking at this code , an entire block of code is being passed as the first parameter instead of a reference to the `TimerTask` class. I've never seen such a method before.  What exactly is happening here?

Some background: The `schedule` method of the `Timer` object is being used to update a feed on Xively(previously COSM(previously pachube)) periodically.

Also I don't know which tag describes what is happening here.If you do please add it or drop in a comment.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I came to know it was related to anonymous-class only after stormehawke's answer.Added the tag later

Comment: The synchronized statement is useless here. Whoever wrote this did not understand what he/she was doing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking at is known as an "Anonymous Inner Class".

See the javadoc here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

and this question:
[How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java).

And, for the record, both of the tags you used in your question are appropriate.

Comment: Also, don't feel bad about not understanding them right away... Anonymous inner classes really threw me for a loop when I first ran across them :)

Answer (score 2):

The method `schedule` here, expects arguments of an `object of class type TimerTask`, and `two other arguments`, probably `int and time in ms`. We are passing an object thorugh the anonymous inner class.

The code is creating an instance of the `TimerTask` class, but we do not even give the class a name – that's [the anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

> GuideLines for Anonymous Class.
>
> 1. Anonymous class is declared and initialized simultaneously.
> 2. Anonymous class must extend or implement to one and only one class or
>    interface resp.
> 3. As anonymous class has no name, it can be used only once.

Answer (score 1):

The logical equivalent of what is happening is:

- Extending the class `TimerTask`, e. g. `MyTimer extends TimerTask`
- Creating an instance of the new class `MyTimer mt = new MyTimer()`
- The actual function call `timer.schedule(mt, 0, 5*1000);`

The concept is called **annonymous inner class**. That's what's happening in step one. Step two and three can also be combined. Instances can directly be created where they're needed. That is called **annonymous object**.

For more insight you should read up on these concepts. They're not hard to grasp. They're often used if you need a standard instance of an interface (for example `ActionListener` in GUI programming).

For completness' sake, there is also an idiom called [**double brace initialization**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization). But it's not a good practice in general.