# How to understand "new {}" syntax in Scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala

I am learning `Scala` multi-thread programming, and write a simple program through referring a tutorial:

```
object ThreadSleep extends App {
  def thread(body: =>Unit): Thread = {
    val t = new Thread {
      override def run() = body
    }
    t.start()
    t
  }
  val t = thread{println("New Therad")}
  t.join
}
```

I can't understand why use `{}` in `new Thread {}` statement. I think it should be `new Thread` or `new Thread()`. How can I understand this syntax?

This question is not completely duplicated to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813503/anonymous-subclass-in-scala), because the point of my question is about the syntax of "`new {}`".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anonymous Subclass in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813503/anonymous-subclass-in-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shortcut for

```
new Thread() { ... }
```

This is called **anonymous class** and it works just like in JAVA: 
You are here creating a new thread, with an overriden `run` method. This is useful because you don't have to create a special class if you only use it once. 
Needs confirmation but you can override, add, redefine every method or attribute you want.

See here for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

By writing `new Thread{}` your creating an anonymous subclass of `Thread` where you're overriding the `run` method. Normally, you'd prefer to create a subclass of `Runnable` and create a thread with it instead of subclassing `Thread`

```
val r = new Runnable{ override def run { body } }
new Thread(r).start
```

This is usually sematincally more correct, since you'd want to subclass `Thread` only if you were specializing the `Thread` class more, for example with an `AbortableThread`. If you just want to run a task on a thread, the `Runnable` approach is more adequate.