# Where do I find tech spec overload abstract method in Java constructor?

Tags: java, wicket

I try Apache Wicket. This framework override abstract methods in java constructor.

Example:

```
public abstract class BasePage extends WebPage {

...
this.add(new Link<Void>("logout") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

I know it is possible to declare Class A whith abstract method my_method and declare Class B extends Class A and define real code for abstract method my_method in class B.

But I don't know any mechanism in Java to override an abstract method in constructor dynamically  like in wicket.

How call these Java technology and where I can find a detailed technical specification of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called anonymous class, more here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Great! Thank you! It's not simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's an anonymous inner class, basically an on-the-fly class for a special purpose that does not merit its own name or file. In some cases, you can see it quite often. [This answer might shed more light on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java) It also contains a link to the oracle specs.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here, on [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) specifications.