# Method inside anonymous inner class

Tags: java, class, anonymous-class

```
    public void run() {
    jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            byte[] buf = createBytesMessage(5120);
            BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
            message.writeBytes(buf);
            message.setLongProperty("_publish_time", System.currentTimeMillis());
            return message;
        }   
    });
}
```

I have this code snippet, what I can make out is its using anonymous class.
But I am confused upon how the createMessage() method will be called when the run() is invoked by thread?

Also somewhere I read there is nothing like "anonymous class" but instead its "anonymous inner class". Why its like that?

Comment: Well, an anonymous inner class is by definition an anonymous class, is it not? Just like a big red apple is a big apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I am confused upon how the createMessage() method will be called
>   when the run() is invoked by thread?

The `jmsTemplate` will expect a `MessageCreator` instance to be passed and it will responsible for calling the MessageCreator's `createMessage()` method.

> Also somewhere I read there is nothing like "anonymous class" but
>   instead its "anonymous inner class". Why its like that?

Yes. The proper definition is *anonymous inner class*, since there is no such thing as *anonymous public class*. While local classes are class declarations, [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) are expressions, which means that you define the class in another expression and so they are called *inner*.

More info:

- [How are anonymous classes used in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

It's an "Anonymous inner class" because it isn't a class that stands by itself, it's a class with some abstract method that you've declared within another class.

As for the method itself, before I look up the class I'm assuming that the handler you send it to (`msTemplate`) just accepts an interface with the method `createMessage`