# Strange java constructor syntax

Tags: java, oop

It seems as if an `ActionListener` object were created with an inherited/overridden method. Has this syntax some special name?

```
btnLocationDev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               ...
    }
});
```

Comment: google for "anonymous class".

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is **anonymous Inner class**. It can actually come in handy when making an instance of an object which something extra such as overloading methods, without having to actually subclass a class. I use it mostly when i want to attach a listner.

When you conventionally attach a listner you have to overload each method but when you use annonymous inner class you just overload the method you want.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Method to be used.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's called anonymous inner class. You just created an instance of anonymous inner class which implements `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 3):

It is an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).                                                                    .