# Java syntax: statement in {} after new

Tags: java, syntax

what is this mean?

```
addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String location = GUI.Custom.QuickDialogs.selectFile(false);
                try
                {
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File(location));
                    String text = textArea.getText();
                    pw.println(text);
                    pw.flush();
                    pw.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    textArea.append("Could not save this debug output");
                }
            }
        });
```

new ActionListener() {} what happened in {}? declare a method in the object?class? is ActionListener inner class?

Comment: Have a look at: [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 7):

The declarations inside curly braces that follow `new ActionListener()` is the definition of an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that extends `ActionListener`.

In your case, the anonymous class provides an implementation of a single method `actionPerformed`. This feature lets you reduce the size of the code and bring declarations closer to the point where they are used in situations when you need a class that is used only from a single place in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is called anonymous class. Generally it's creating new implementation of *ActionListener* interface and overloading *actionPerformed* method.

Its equivalent of

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String location = GUI.Custom.QuickDialogs.selectFile(false);
        ...
    }
}

addActionListener(new MyActionListener())
```

More information can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

With this statement you are creating new `ActionListener` object with added new method `actionPerformed`.

This is equal to creating new class which extends `ActionListener` like:

```
class MyActionListener extends ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // ...
    }

}

addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

this syntax is anonymous class it is basically derived class which overrides the functionality, but as it is used only in this place probably there is no need of naming it.

They are pretty much created for same reasons as lambda statements, if something is being used only in one place of code why would you actually bother to name it, making the class or namespace bigger, polluting it.

Comment: It's not about "bothering to name it", it's about not polluting the global name space with internal functions. It's encapsulation, not laziness.

Comment: Yes indeed, this is what I mean by "making the class or namespace bigger". I will add the polluting word though if you like it so much.

Answer (score 0):

That's an anonymous inner class, a form of syntactic sugar to simplify writing single-use classes (often implementations of interfaces).

You can read more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

The "anonymous inner class" is a common idiom for setting up things like listeners.  However, in Java 8, since `ActionListener` has only one method, it's now possible to use a lambda expression to do the same thing.  The compiler will figure out that you're providing an implementation of `actionPerformed`.

```
addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            String location = GUI.Custom.QuickDialogs.selectFile(false);
            try
            {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File(location));
                String text = textArea.getText();
                pw.println(text);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                textArea.append("Could not save this debug output");
            }
        });
```

The first line could just be

```
addActionListener(e -> {
```

since the compiler will figure out that `e` must be an `ActionEvent`; a human reader might find it more difficult to spot it, though, depending on how familiar they are with AWT.