# Java abstract class constructor and new keyword

Tags: java, oop, constructor, abstract

I am a junior developer and I am familiar with the theory behind java abstract classes and how they can have constructors to force subclasses to set certain constructor parameters, and how abstract classes themselves cannot be instantiated. However, when looking at some refactored code in my company's test framework I am slightly puzzled.

This abstract class

```
public abstract class WaitForTestOutcomeThenAssert {

   private long maxWait;

   public WaitForTestOutcomeThenAssert(long maxWait) {
      this.maxWait = maxWait;
   }

   public void waitForConditionThenAssert() {
    ...
    ...
   }

   protected abstract boolean checkCondition();
}
```

gets referenced in this class:

```
public class DbWrapper extends AbstractDB {

    @Override
    public void assertColumnValueNotNull(final String schema, final String table, final String columnName, final String whereClause) {

        new WaitForTestOutcomeThenAssert(this.assertionTemporalTolerance) {

             @Override
             public boolean checkCondition() {
                 return getColumnValue(schema, table, columnName, whereClause) != null;
             }
       }.waitForConditionThenAssert();
   }
}
```

Since we can't instantiate an abstract class, can someone please explain to me exactly what happens and what gets created when we use *new* keyword in front of an abstract class constructor?

Comment: That is an [anonymous class](http://www.docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm). Basically a class declared inline without a name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

Comment: See this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). Here you have an anonymous class declaration that extends abstract class `WaitForTestOutcomeThenAssert` and overrides `checkCondition` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an abstract class

```
  new WaitForTestOutcomeThenAssert(this.assertionTemporalTolerance) {

         @Override
         public boolean checkCondition() {
             return getColumnValue(schema, table, columnName, whereClause) != null;
         }
   }
```

That is an anonymous class that extends WaitForTestOutcomeThenAssert. In other words, by writing that you are subclassing "WaitForTestOutcomeThenAssert" and instantiating it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an *Anonymous* class. It's a shortcut to use *Abstract* class or *Interface* without having to explicitly write a subclass.