# What is called anonymous class?

Tags: java

```
abstract class Inner_Class_1{
  abstract void call();
}

class AnnonymousInner{
  public static void main(String args[]){

    Inner_Class_1 p=new Inner_Class_1()
    {
      void call()
      {
        System.out.println("nice fruits");
      }
    };

    p.call();
  }
}
```

1. What happens behind the scenes?
2. Is object created for abstract class named `Inner_Class_1`?
3. Why this is called an anonymous class?

Please, help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

Comment: you should extend the abstract class

Comment: If you want comprehensible answers, you need to ask comprehensible questions.

Comment: 0) What is "what"?  1) Magic!  2) No.  3) Because it has no name.

Answer (score 1):

No, an object is created for an anonymous class that is a sub-class of `Inner_Class_1`. Anonymous means the class has no name.