# Enumeration Interface's elements() method

Tags: collections, enumeration

How the statement return new Enumeration() is possible, since Enumeration is an Interface. Plz explain. Thanks.

```
public Enumeration<E> elements() {
    return new Enumeration<E>() {
        int count = 0;

        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return count < elementCount;
        }

        public E nextElement() {
            synchronized (Vector.this) {
                if (count < elementCount) {
                    return elementData(count++);
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible because it **implements** the *Enumeration* **interface** through an *anonymous inner class*.

Interfaces are defined to be implemented, and the use of an *anonymous inner class* is simply a shortcut, that works the same way as when you instantiate an *abstract class* (you must implement the abstract methods). In this case, you must implement ALL of the interface methods.