# Java curly braces after new

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to Java and stumbled upon this snippet of code that's used for CA cert bypass. I'm having trouble understanding the curly braces after new for TrustManager[] and X509TrustManager(). Could someone shed some light? Thanks.

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Look up: anonymous inner class, such the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java).

Comment: For the benefit of the OP, this question is compounded by having an array of instances of type TrustManager - `... = new TrustManager[] { ... };` It just so happens your array `{ ... }` contains one object that is an inner class implementing the X509TrustManager interface - `new X509TrustManager() { // implemented methods }`

Comment: `new TM { ... }` is an array initialization, here of 1 element, an anonymous child of  `new X509TM()` implemented as class { pu.... }.