# Anonymous inner classes and good practice

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, standards

I am learning Android from a few tutorials, and when it comes to using OnClickListeners, I notice that a lot of them use anonymous inner classes like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mNameField;
    private Button mStartButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = mNameField.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Is this considered good practice to have a class inside a class? Or is it considered better to somehow define this class outside somewhere and then reference it? How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

Comment: @AndrewRegan I know how they are used -- but I am asking if they are considered good practice.

Comment: The android documentation is not too suggestive about what approach is the 'best' but if you have a few buttons in a layout you wouldn't create anonymous classes for each button. That becomes cumbersome. Instead consider implementing OnClickListener as a part of your Activity/Fragment.

Comment: @Susheel How would I do that? I posted more code above. If I wanted to implement the listener not as an inner class, that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to duplicate some code, you should do some refactoring and define it only in one place. In case of using it in a single class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //some code
    }
};

mStartButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

When you use the same listener in multiple classes

```
public class WidelyUsedOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //some code
    }
```

}
Then in your Activity

```
WidelyUsedOnClickLister onClickListener = new WidelyUsedOnClickLister();
mStartButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Inner Class` Concept only came when without existing one `Objcet` (**Class**) there is no scope to exist another `Object`(**Class**). then you can create a `class` inside a `Class`.

This Concept is came in `Java v1.1` when `AWT` is introduced in Java to perform `eventhandling` . As you used in your code

```
mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

here `Click` event if and only there is `Clickable Object` exists (eg:- **Button,or anyOther**). So, `EventListener`must be associate only with those  `components` which actually needs it. this makes sense...

> ==========Alternatives=============

You may also implement `OnClickListener()` to any other Custom `Event Handler` Class.  but it will be a very hectic task to do so, because if you used `6`(**suppose**) Clickable Componenets then you must **write** `six` different `Class EventHandler` and pass this `Class` at

```
                    new View.OnClickListener(new CustomEventHandler())
```

Hope you got the concept.. There are so many more consequences but You should think atleast once. You Might get your answer.