# Curled brackets as an argument to a function

Tags: java

I have a method login() that calls another method registerLoginHandler().  The thing that is confusing to me is that the arguments of registerLoginHandler() contain a lot of stuff inside curled brackets.  It's almost as if it is passing an entire class to registerLoginHandler().  Could someone shed some light on what is going on here?

```
public static ITeamRepository login() throws TeamRepositoryException {
    ITeamRepository repository = TeamPlatform.getTeamRepositoryService().getTeamRepository(REPOSITORY_ADDRESS);
    repository.registerLoginHandler(new ITeamRepository.ILoginHandler() {
        public ILoginInfo challenge(ITeamRepository repository) {
            return new ILoginInfo() {
                public String getUserId() {
                    return "UserName";
                }
                public String getPassword() {
                    return "Password";
                }
            };
        }
    });

    monitor.subTask("Contacting " + repository.getRepositoryURI() + "...");
    repository.login(monitor);
    monitor.subTask("Connected");
    return repository;
}
```

Comment: It's called an anonymous class instance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java

Comment: *It's almost as if it is passing an entire class to registerLoginHandler().* That's exactly what it's doing.

Comment: It is an anonymous interface implementation.