# Why are anonymous classes called that when we provide a name?

Tags: java

I am a little bit confused about the explanation of the anonymous classes in Java.

I understand the purpose of such classes, but why are they called classes without a name? Is it because the compiler do not include the name that we provide?

Comment: What "name that we provide"?  The whole point of an anonymous class is that you didn't explicitly define it with a name.

Comment: No, it's not because the compiler does not include the name, it's because we literally do not provide a name for these classes.

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java

Comment: *why they are also called classes without a name?* Because they have no name. Don't confuse interface name and class name: `new ActionListener() {/* anonymous class implementation */}` -> here `ActionListener` is **not** the anonymous class name, it's just the interface name. The anonymous class is the implementation (code between curly braces) and as you can see it has no name.

Comment: Ok now i get it, thank you :)

Comment: Anonymous classes just like any class have names. The only difference is that the name is auto generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name we provide is not the name of the anonymous class, it's the name of the interface we're implementing or the class we're extending.

Consider the example from [the Anonymous Classes tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
interface HelloWorld {
    public void greet();
    public void greetSomeone(String someone);
}

/* ... */

HelloWorld frenchGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
    String name = "tout le monde";
    public void greet() {
        greetSomeone("tout le monde");
    }
    public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
        name = someone;
        System.out.println("Salut " + name);
    }
}
```

Clearly we already have something named `HelloWorld`, so the class is not that, it's a new class which implements `HelloWorld`.

Also from the above tutorial:

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>
> - The new operator
> - **The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend**. In this example, the anonymous class is implementing the interface HelloWorld.
> - Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a normal class instance creation expression. Note: When you implement an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of parentheses, as in this example.
> - A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.