# What is the proper syntax for actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)?

Tags: java, eclipse, physics

```
package Kinematics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Display extends JFrame implements Runnable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 938633141149262027L;

static JButton b2 = new JButton("v/t");
static JButton b1 = new JButton("d/t");
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Kinematics Conversions");
static JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Kinematics Conversions");



public static void main(String[] args){
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    b1.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
    b1.addActionListener(ActionListener -> {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ //says actionPerformed cannot have void return type
            if(b2.getModel().isPressed()) { //however the oracle site says otherwise
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
    b2.setBounds(50, 50, 5, 5);
    p.add(b1);
    p.add(b2);
    frame.add(p);
    frame.pack();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if(b2.getModel().isPressed()) {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }
}

}
```

Ok, so I have the correct syntax.. i think. I went onto the oracle website to look at the syntax and the proper return type however ECLIPSE OXYGEN 2.0 says that actionPerformed cannot have a return type of void. Why is that?

Comment: I am quite sure your syntax is wrong. You either want `.addActionListener(new ActionListener{...` (annonymous class) or `.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> { ...` (add the body of `actionPerformed(...)` here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make up your mind.

You can **either** use an anonymous inner class (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java), there is an example for action listeners right there).

Or you use java8 style [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) expressions.

Your current code is just a mix of both ideas. Invalid syntax, coming out of the idea of putting together two completely different approaches.

Comment: Ok, I did some more research and it appears that i was majorly confused. Sorry for wasting your time :(