# Why making new Greeting() as Greeting is an interface in lambdas expression?

Tags: java, lambda

**Greeter.java**

```
package lambda;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Greeter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Greeting Greet1 = () -> System.out.println("Hello gretting..");

        Greeting innerclass = new Greeting() {
            //why new Greeting is an interface ?
            public void perform(){
                System.out.println("Hello inner greeting");
            }
        };
        Greet1.perform();
        innerclass.perform();
    }
}
```

**Greeting.java**

```
package lambda;

public interface Greeting {

    public void perform();

}
```

> **OUTPUT**

***Hello gretting..***

***Hello inner greeting...***

why this line is working?

```
Greeting innerclass = new Greeting() {
```

Comment: Please read about anonymous classes in java. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java

Comment: It's also worth noting that lambda expressions in Java are effectively just a cleaner syntax for an single-method anonymous inner class - `Greet1` and `innerclass` are functionally identical.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Greeting innerclass = new Greeting() ...` creates an **anonymous inner class** that implements the `Greeting` inteface.

Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html