# How to create an anonymous class using a method that returns a reference to a class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I want to create an anonymous class using a method that returns an instance of a class

```
class FirstClass {
    public FirstClass() {
        System.out.println("First class created");
    }
}

class SecondClass {
    public SecondClass() {
        System.out.println("Second class created");
    }
    public FirstClass getFirstClass() {
        return new FirstClass();
    }
}

public class Ex1 {
    public FirstClass getFirstClass() {
        return new FirstClass();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //here is the problem
        Object obj = new SecondClass().getFirstClass() {
            {
                System.out.println("Anonymous class created");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I expect program to work by creating the anonymous class, but it gives me a syntax error. Any solutions or workarounds are accepted. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java

You're misunderstanding what anon classes are

Comment: i have a task and thos are the conditions

Comment: You can't subclass an _instance_ of a class. That is a misunderstanding of what a subclass is.

Comment: You clearly didn't read both your teacher's instructions nor the link I provided.

Comment: i need to use anonymous class and create it from a reference to a class - thats the task

Comment: @AlexJidras Regardless, this is a very bad design pattern to use

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to be creating a subclass of `SecondClass` and possibly overriding `getFirstClass`?

Comment: “…and create it from a reference to a class” what is “a reference to a class” in this context? The method `getFirstClass()` returns a reference to an object, not to a class. Further, when you use `new` you always create a new object and there’s no relationship between than new object and the object returned by `getFirstClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an anonymous class based on return value of a method. Anonymous classes can only be created *upon creation of the object*, meaning, it can only be created using a constructor.

Your best bet would be to just create `FirstClass` directly, and override the initializer, like so:

```java
new FirstClass() {
    {
        System.out.println("This is from inside anon!");
    }
};
```