# What does the keyword object mean in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

The Code A is from [CameraXBasic](https://github.com/mycwcgr/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt)

I can't understand completely the code p`rivate val volumeDownReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver()`.

I think the Code B will work well, but in fact it failed.

What does the keyword object mean in Kotlin ?

**Code A**

```
private val volumeDownReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
private val volumeDownReceiver = BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `object` keyword can also be used to create [anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java). Using that, you are saying that you want to override one or more member of either concrete or abstract member. This way, you don't need to create a separate class to and trim down the functionality to your needs. I would suggest reading about [object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Code A `val volumeDownReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver()` refers to creating an object of an anonymous class that inherits from type `BroadcastReceiver`.

In Code B `val volumeDownReceiver = BroadcastReceiver()` tries to instantiate a new instance of an abstract class and that's why it's failing.

Edit: link to docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions